# I found unexpected numbers while working on perfect numbers

Tags: pascal

my code prints "6 24 24 24 24 28 496". i don't want the 24s. how can i solve this problem?

```
program perfect;
uses crt;
var i,number,temp:integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    for number:=2 to 999 do begin
        temp:=1;
        for i:=2 to Trunc(number/2) do begin
            if (number mod i = 0) then
                temp:=temp+i;
                if(temp=number) then
                    writeln(number);
        end;
    end;
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: What are you even trying to accomplish? What's up with that sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the if statement.
The code should be:

```
program perfect;
var i,number,temp:integer;
begin
    for number:=2 to 999 do begin
        temp:=1;
        for i:=2 to Trunc(number/2) do begin
            if (number mod i = 0) then
                temp:=temp+i;
                //Instead of here
        end;
                //Here
        if(temp=number) then
                    writeln(number);
    end;
    readln;
end.
```

In that form it works fine(I got 6,28 and 496)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull the `if(temp=number)` part out of the inner `for` loop, I think.

Since 1+2+3+4+6+8 is 24, you're getting output for `number=24` and `i=8, 9, 10, 11`.